# Get Text from File Bytes Without using Temp File

Tags: c#

I have a function that is returning the bytes of a text file containing a JSON object to my code, and I need a way to retrieve the contents of that file as a string, then parse it to a C# object.

I have tried using the `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString()` and `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` methods to parse the byte array, but consistently get a `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: ?.` error when I try to deserialize it (more detail below).

If it makes any difference, this is in .NET 6.0.

Example code:

```
// p is a byte[] being returned from a function earlier in the code.
// To copy the code I'm using exactly, use:
// var p = new byte[] { 255, 254, 123, 0, 34, 0, 114, 0, 101, 0, 99, 0, 116, 0, 115, 0, 34, 0, 58, 0, 91, 0, 93, 0, 44, 0, 34, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 120, 0, 116, 0, 34, 0, 58, 0, 34, 0, 34, 0, 125, 0 };
// A text file created with these bytes can be opened like normal.

// Blindly parsing the file bytes to string
var p2 = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(p);
//var p2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(p); Doesn't work either


// Fails
dynamic p3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(p2);

Console.WriteLine(p3.text);
Console.WriteLine(p3.rects);
```

This is the error I get:

`Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: ?. Path '', line 0, position 0.`

Thanks!

Comment: [ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-7.0) doesn't work for you because ... ? I really don't get why you think you need to save the bytearray to another file to use it.

Comment: The question is unclear. `File.ReadAllText` reads the existing file either with the default encoding or whatever you pass as a parameter. It doesn't generate any temporary files. If you want to deserialize a JSON file, use JsonSerializer and the `DeserializeXXX` method that accepts a Stream or TextReader

Comment: I don't actually have a file on my computer. I used ReadAllBytes in my example code to avoid adding a several lines of extraneous code. I'll modify my example to make this more clear. I can't use ReadAllText because I only have a byte array.

Comment: Oh, nevermind! Now I get it ... _"In reality this is coming from a different function and can't be modified"_ - Didn't read this at first look.

Comment: `I only have a byte array` in that case modify the question and explain the *actual* problem. The [JSON.NET Serialization quickstart](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm#JsonSerializer) shows how you can use a StreamReader or StreamWriter. You can use that to read from a MemoryStream that wraps that buffer. You *do* need to know what encoding was used though - UTF8? Latin1? Something else?

Comment: Have you tried to have a look at the plain text to see what it actually looks like and what could be the problem? To me it seems it could be one of several problems: The bytearray could contain a BOM. The data could be broken (not be valid json) to start with, maybe wrong encoding ...

Comment: @Fildor Yes - the JSON string is very long though so I haven't been able to identify what particularly is causing the problem. If I save the bytes to a file, then read them using `ReadAllText`, there is no problem deserializing the object. Sorry, what is a BOM? I haven't seen that acronym before.

Comment: What's the buffer's encoding? The method that produced that buffer *must* specify it somewhere, probably in the docs, probably as a parameter

Comment: BOM = Byte Order Mark, it may be handled for you if you use framework methods to read text, but if you are using the bytes directly, it may come around and bite you. It's just a "usual suspect", though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The problem is that the byte array represents a text file, not a string. Would wrapping the byte array in a stream reader cause c# to interpret it as a file instead of a raw string? The only documentation I have doesn't say anything other than it is a byte[] that represents a .txt file. I believe it's standard though, because I can save it to a file on my computer and open it with notepad just fine.

Comment: @Fildor Ahh okay, thank you - can that appear anywhere, or only at the beginning? I noticed that the byte array starts with "??", which is why I also tried using `DeserializeObject<dynamic>(p2.Substring(2))` to skip those first two characters, but parsing just failed somewhere later on in the text.

Comment: The BOM is (_if_ it exists) _always_ at the very beginning of the file. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @CalebKeller `The problem is that the byte array represents a text file, not a string.` that statement is self-contradictory. A text file contains a string. Either that byte array is a string with the file's contents or it's a path to the file. If it's a path, you need to convert it to a string so you can use `File.ReadAllText` or `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`. If it's the file's contents, you can convert it to a string again or use a MemoryStream on top so you can use `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` without having to convert to a string

Comment: In both cases, use `JsonSerializer` instead of `JsonConvert` to read from the stream directly. Right now you're making a copy of the data in memory when you create a string. That just wastes memory

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `Either that byte array is a string with the file's contents or it's a path to the file.` This is not quite the case - the byte array *does* contain the file's contents, but it also contains other metadata and special characters that make it impossible to convert to a string directly. I mentioned this in my comments and question multiple times.

Comment: You didn't. That's the first comment that mentions `metadata`. Not that it matters - without actual code and data it's impossible to help. Your own answer contradicts this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What other code or data would you suggest I include? My example code explains that `p` is a byte array, equivalent to calling `File.ReadAllBytes()`. If you'd like to reproduce the problem, use `var p = File.ReadAllBytes(@"text.txt")` at the top, then paste the remaining example code in and try it. I can provide example JSON too if that would help, though since I'm using a `dynamic` it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You didn't post any data. The code explains nothing, it shows a misunderstanding of UTF8 and BOM. You tried reading a UTF8 file using Latin1. Had you used `StreamReader` as others suggested your code would just work, because `StreamReader` uses UTF8 and BOM detection. Your own answer proves this

Comment: I suggest reading [UTF-8 BOM Adventures in C#](https://danielwertheim.se/utf-8-bom-adventures-in-c/) which explains what Byte Order Marks are, what their values are, how to check your data to see if they appear in it, how to produce them or read buffers that contain them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay, I updated the question with copy-and-paste example code and explained the error I'm getting. Thanks for the suggesting! I'll check it out.